# Does the Great Firewall Of China Modify X-Forwarded-For

Tags: networking, proxy, china

I'm looking at traffic from some of our Chinese customers and their X-Forwarded-For's look something like:

```
REALIP, 127.0.0.1, REALIP, etc
```

The interesting thing is the loopback IP is always the second IP address in the list. This implies the connection is going from workstation -> proxy -> proxy on the same host -> another proxy.

This implies that the traffic is going through a proxy on a local machine somewhere.

Is this the Great Firewall? I always figured it would be a transparent proxy. Something else? Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks.

Comment: . . . you should really be asking the Chinese government. (I'm only being a little facetious -- It's pretty hard for anyone here to speak with authority on what China is doing or may elect to do in the future. Of course I don't expect China to be forthcoming with that information either...)